# Enclosing jQuery functions and adding them to global namespace

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having a lot of issues with jquery. I am managing an older application that used prototype. My new pages don't use prototype, but I am encapsulating things in jquery.noConflict just in case. This however is resulting in me being unable to share functions through different js files.

Order files are loaded:

```
jquery.js
jquery.commonFuncs.js
jquery.database.js
```

Example contents of files

**commonFuncs.js**

```
var someGlobalVar = "abc";

jQuery.noConflict()(function($){

  function doStuff(x){
     return x;
  }

});
```

**database.js**

```
jQuery.noConflict()(function($){
  var a = 123;
  doStuff(a);
});
```

`Error`: doStuff is not defined.

I can kind of understand why encapsulating the function removes it from the global namespace. How can I add it back?

I also have no darn idea why I have to use noConflict if I do not load prototype.js If I *completely* remove prototype.js and remove the noConflict encapsulation, I get $ is undefined, and I don't know where to start with that. jQuery is clearly loading first. No clue.

Comment: Create a global object and assign the functions you're defining as properties on that object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Madbreaks proposed, something like in the example below should work. 
(Have a look in the web browser console to see that there's no error message.)

```js
var someGlobalVar = "abc";
var myApp = {};

jQuery.noConflict()(function($){

  function doStuff(x){
     return x;
  }

  myApp.doStuff = doStuff;
}); 

jQuery.noConflict()(function($){
  var a = 123;
  //doStuff(a);
  console.log(myApp.doStuff(a));  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can refactor your code like this:

```
 var someGlobalVar = "abc";
 var doStuff;
 jQuery.noConflict()(function($){

  doStuff = function(x){
     return x;
  }

 });
```